# postgreSQL coalesce on a json array

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm currently working on a PSQL database with the following tables:

**TABLE A**

```
name  | character varying(500)
data  | jsonb
```

**TABLE B**

```
height  | character varying(255)   | not null
history | character varying(255)[] | not null default '{}'::character varying[]
someField | character varying(255)[] | not null default ARRAY[]::character varying[]
```

Now,I have to insert the values of the JSON fields from the "data" column on table A, into the history and someField columns on table B using COALESCE, but with no success.

My query:

```
INSERT INTO TABLEb (history,someField) 
SELECT 
COALESCE(i.data->>'history','{}') AS history
COALESCE(i.data->>'someField','[]') AS someField
FROM TABLEa i
```

My error:

> column "history" is of type character varying[] but expression is of
>   type text

Thanks.

Comment: `i.data->>'history'` is a text, and even `i.data->'history'` would still be jsonb, not `character varying(255)[]` array. why you decided to use `character varying(255)[]` for data type?..

Comment: This was caused because of changes related to another service that inserting data into TABLE B

Answer (score 0):

`i.data->>'history'` is a text, and even `i.data->'history'` would still be jsonb, not character `varying(255)[]` array. You have to aggregate unnested jsonb array to achieve that.

example:

```
t=# with c(j) as (values('{"a":["a","b"]}'::jsonb))
, a as (select j,jsonb_array_elements_text(j->'a') ja from c)
select j, array_agg(ja) from a group by j;
         j         | array_agg
-------------------+-----------
 {"a": ["a", "b"]} | {a,b}
(1 row)
```